# Random Forest in R memory error

Tags: r

I am running a random forest on a relatively small csv that is 250 mb.  I have 16 Gb of ram on my machine.  I am running a random forest on it like so:

```
libarary(randomForest)

df <- read.csv("Z:\\path_to_csv.csv")

x <- df[, 2:ncol(df)]
y <- df[, 'Target']

rf <- randomForest(x = x, y = y)
```

which immediately results in:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.2 Gb
```

When I run the same model using python's sklearn my memory barely even moves though so I don't understand this.

Comment: try ranger package for random forest- it much faster (paralleled) and manages memory much better. I could easily model data in ranger for which randomForest would ran out of memory. Article about ranger: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v077i01

Comment: This package looks very promising and the documentation (with r code included) are phenomenal, thank you.

Comment: @ilya out of curiosity, why is the gini importance not scaled from 0 - 1 in ranger?

Comment: I don't know :). If i recall correctly  you get counts of splits for each variable, I did resale it manually. Oh one more thing, ranger really doesn't like NAs in your data set - even in variables you don't use. Use na.omit function to quickly remove NAs.

Comment: I figured it out, it is decrease in impurity, for some reason it is 0 -100000 but I also just re-scaled it manually.  This package is quite amazing for speed and memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to increase the memory limit at the begging of the script.

```
memory.limit(10 * 10^10)
```